# MySQL Deleting Multiple Records

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-delete, records

I have a database with a bunch of shops and once a month someone sends me a spreadsheet with the cancellations for that month so I need to delete 30-40 shops each month.

Is there a quick way to do it?  Right now I just manually go in and delete them because sometimes there is only 8-10 but this last spreadsheet had a bunch and I would love to make this process a lot faster.

Comment: is there any common feature in the shops you're going to delete?

Comment: I know in SQL Server you could import the excel sheet into the DB, then use a join to find the shops that match your spreadsheet and delete those.  But, I don't ever use MySQL, so I don't know if they have an Import interface like that ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how technical you want to get, you could create an process that takes your spreadsheet as an input and deletes the ones listed in there.  It would then be advisable to keep the spreadsheet structure the same every time.

Otherwise, you could simply use a SQL statement as such

```
delete from stores where store_id in (:ids);
```

or

```
delete from stores where store_name in (:names);
```

and manually copy the list of store IDs or names as a comma delimited list where the :variable is.  If you are using names, just be sure each name is enclosed with ' .

Comment: +1, this would work (and certainly be faster than the way the OP has to do it right now).

Comment: Thanks! That will probably work great.  Although I would have to delete from the account number, and SOME shops have the same account number.. not many but some do, so that could be bad.

Comment: @drew you would simply have to replace where ___ with whatever is a distinguishable attribute for your store.  I imagine there has to be a way to distinguish store A from store B.

Comment: What about another query I could run before, to see if there are any duplicates first.  Would that work?  if nothing, then I am OK to run the delete query.

Comment: @Drew: One quick way to check for dupes in your AccountNumber field: `SELECT AccountNumber, COUNT(*) AS NumRecords FROM stores GROUP BY AccountNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.  This returns only AccountNumbers with dupes, and how many there are =)

Comment: Yep, jadarnel's query would help you identify those.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether these shops has something in common that let you classify them. In MySql,  the syntax is `DELETE FROM tableName WHERE condition;` where `tableName` is the name of the table where you are going to perform the `DELETE` query, and  `condition` is a boolean expression that tells the DBMS how to classify them: i.e:

```
DELETE FROM shop WHERE NOW() - last_activity > 7;
```

That would eliminate shops that have been inactive for more than a week.